# Simple api auth with static key

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony4

I've got my project API secured by symfony security firewalls, got user providers and more. Now I need few public routes secured only with single token, I mean single random 32 char string and not need user provider, jwt token etc, just check this static string matches mine or not and respond. Is there better way in symfony(4) than using kernel events on every request event?

Comment: Basic auth, using the web server. What you describe does not appear to be a job for the application.

Comment: Better way than which one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a class I've used for another project where **all** routes should be secured by a URL token:

```php
<?php

namespace App\AccessControl;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class AccessControlSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    private string $token;

    public function __construct(string $token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => 'onKernelController',
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $event): void
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();

        if (!is_array($controller)) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if (0 === strpos($request->getPathInfo(), '/_profiler') || 0 === strpos($request->getPathInfo(), '/_fragment')) {
            return;
        }

        $token = $request->query->get('token');

        if ($this->token !== $token || $this->token === '') {
            throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('This action needs a valid token!');
        }
    }
}
```

It hooks into all kernel events where a controller is used, right before the controller's arguments are resolved and the controller action itself is called. The profiler routes are excluded, such that you can still use it.

---

If you want to use this only for **some** controllers, you could check for specific classes set in the `$controller` array, just like I did it for the routes of the profiler toolbar